# Is there a way to use Datatables for in asp.net for a table created using gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatables

Below is the code for what i have started for my project currently. I am updating the new 
code. I am getting an error of Gridview1 does not exist.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title spellcheck="true"Glossary</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 208px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="margin-left: 720px">

        <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" BackColor="#F7F6F3" BorderColor="#E6E2D8" BorderPadding="4" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#333333">
            <InstructionTextStyle Font-Italic="True" ForeColor="Black" />
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style1">
                            <table cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" colspan="2">Log In</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" Text="Remember me next time." />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                        <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID"></asp:Literal>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right" colspan="2">
                                        <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="Login1" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <LoginButtonStyle BackColor="#FFFBFF" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <TextBoxStyle Font-Size="0.8em" />
            <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="0.9em" ForeColor="White" />

        </asp:Login>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    </div>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="TedGlossary" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Glsry_Taylor %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [TermText], [DefNbr], [DefVerNbr], [DefText], [AmplifyingExplanationText], [SeeAlsoText], [AuthoritativeSrcText], [ScopeName], [DomnName], [GovernanceStateName], [LastUpdtTimestamp] FROM [Glossary] ORDER BY [TermText]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"

            " DataKeyNames="TermText,DefNbr,DefVerNbr" DataSourceID="TedGlossary" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True">

            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TermText" HeaderText="Term" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TermText" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DefNbr" HeaderText="Definition #" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DefNbr" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DefVerNbr" HeaderText="Definition Vers #" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DefVerNbr" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DefText" HeaderText="Definition" SortExpression="DefText" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AmplifyingExplanationText" HeaderText="Amplifying Explanation" SortExpression="AmplifyingExplanationText" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SeeAlsoText" HeaderText="See Also" SortExpression="SeeAlsoText" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AuthoritativeSrcText" HeaderText="Authoritative Source" SortExpression="AuthoritativeSrcText" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ScopeName" HeaderText="Scope Name" SortExpression="ScopeName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DomnName" HeaderText="Domn Name" SortExpression="DomnName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="GovernanceStateName" HeaderText="Governance State" SortExpression="GovernanceStateName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastUpdtTimestamp" HeaderText="Last Update" SortExpression="LastUpdtTimestamp" />
            </Columns>


        </asp:GridView>

    </form>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').dataTable();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there something that i am missing. I need to be able to filter results using some sort of search.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Home
{
    public partial class Glossary : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.PreRender += new EventHandler(GridView1_PreRender);
        }
        protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
           {
             //forces grid to render thead/th elements 
             GridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = true; 
             GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
           }
}
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question. You want to use "datatables" to search? Do you mean the datatables library?

Comment: I want to use the datatables library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I think you are referring to the [datatables](http://datatables.net/) jquery plugin.)

Yes, it's possible. You need to make sure your GridView generates the `thead` tags in your table, so you need to do the following:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PreRender += new EventHandler(GridView1_PreRender);
}



protected void GridView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
   {
     //forces grid to render thead/th elements 
     GridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = true; 
     GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
   }
}
```

Now you can simply do:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#<%=Gridview1.ClientID%>').dataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @lcarus where do i put the $(function(){
    $('#<%=Gridview1.ClientID%>').dataTable();
});

Comment: @Absent_Dev inside a pair of script tags, provided you include jQuery, obviously... see my update...

Comment: @lcarus I added the script but i am getting an error of GridView1 does not exist in its current context any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is definitely possible, but I've never tried it with a SqlDataSource.  Here's how I'd do it:

1. Add a `TextBox` and `Button` to your page.
2. On the `Button`'s `Click` event, you'll want to read the text in your `TextBox` and query your database.
3. This is where it can diverge.  You can use the old-school `ADO.NET` (`SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, etc), or you can do it as `LINQ to Entities`, which is the newer way.  Which way are you more familiar with?  I'll tailor the answer based on your response.